# Why processor stores data in reverse-byte sequence

Tags: assembly, microprocessors

I am studying assembly language. I have a doubt that why processor stores data in reverse-byte sequence, i.e., a low-order byte is stored in a low memory address and a high-order byte in high memory address. So, if the processor brings the value 0725H from register to memory, it will transfer 25 first to the lower memory address and 07 to the next memory address.

Register  ---->    07     25, memory    ---->    25     07

Comment: Which processor? Not every one and some are configurable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @Ped7g I am studying 8085 microprocessor

Comment: [What is the advantage of little endian format?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/95556/98103), [What benefits does the use of the little-endian notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11641132/995714), [What are the advantages of using Big Endian over Little Endian in a computer architecture?](http://qr.ae/TU1JCR)