# Move number to memory with different sizes

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, move, cpu-registers

I am learning Assembly and I found something I don't understand clearly.

If I have code like this

```
section .data
    var dw 0x10, 0x20, 0x30

section .text
    ; ...
    mov edx, dword 0x12345678
    mov [var], edx
    ; ...
```

I do know already, that result will be

```
[var] = 0x5678
[var + 2] = 0x1234
```

I just don't know what happened inside.

Why was `dx = 0x5678` stored as the first element and not the second? And after this half is stored, does the first half of `edx` suddenly becomes `word` instead of `double word`?

How it works at all, if I attempt to put a bigger number into memory than it is reserved (let's say  `256` into `var_b resb 1`)?

Thank you.

Comment: low half goes last is the rule for x86, `dh=0x56`, `dl=0x78`

Comment: So after `dx` is stored, `0x1234` moves from `edx` to `dx` and it is stored as the first part ?

Comment: `dx` is low half of `edx`, and for 64-bit `edx` is low part of `rdx`. If you move something in `edx`, you also move in `dx`,`dh`,`dl`. Also read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: use a debugger to see what happens with registers

Comment: You told me why is `0x5678` stored as first, but i don't understand how is the first part stored as second element..

Comment: when I run the code I've got in var memory  `0x804908c: 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12`

Answer (score 3):

Your code stores `0x12345678` in `edx`, and then copy the value from `edx` in place where the `var` is placed.
Lowest byte(8 bit) goes first when they are storied in memory from a register, because [x86 processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185551/why-is-x86-little-endian) are [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Code compiled by `nasm`:

```
global _start

section .data
    var dw 0x10, 0x20, 0x30

section .text
_start:

mov edx, dword 0x12345678
mov [var], edx

; quit the program
mov eax, 1      ; sys_exit system call
push dword 0        ; program return value
push eax
int 0x80        ; call the kernel
```

Debugger:

```
(gdb) b _start 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048080
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ssssssssssssssss/test 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048080 in _start ()
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x08048080 <+0>: mov    edx,0x12345678
   0x08048085 <+5>: mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x804908c,edx
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/4x 0x804908c
0x804908c:  0x10 0x0 0x20 0x0
(gdb) si
0x08048085 in _start ()
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x08048080 <+0>: mov    edx,0x12345678
=> 0x08048085 <+5>: mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x804908c,edx
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) i r
eax            0x0  0
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x12345678   305419896
ebx            0x0  0
esp            0xbfffee70   0xbfffee70
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x8048085    0x8048085 <_start+5>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
(gdb) si
0x0804808b in ?? ()
(gdb) x/4x 0x804908c
0x804908c:  0x78    0x56    0x34    0x12
(gdb)
```

objdump:

```
test:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048080 <_start>:
 8048080:       ba 78 56 34 12          mov    edx,0x12345678
 8048085:       89 15 8c 90 04 08       mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x804908c,edx
```

https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers

Comment: I am sorry but this debugger message didn't help me at all, i asked how the mechanism works if i store a number with bigger size into reserved memory of smaller size.  
If `edx = 0x12345678`, i know that first 16 bits by Little endian are stored first. Problem is that i don't know how it continues. 
I have `[var+0] = 0x5678` and `edx = 0x12345678` and i don't know how it is rotated or shifted or what so `0x1234` end's up in `[var+2]` if `edx` hasn't changed at all.

Comment: @SevO: [var] points on a byte, I think you get it if you debug the following: `xor edx,edx
mov edx, [var]
xor edx,edx
mov dx, [var]
xor edx,edx
mov dl, [var]
xor edx,edx
mov dh, [var]`

Comment: @SevO:Do you use debugger or just think how it will work?

Comment: I am using a program which can display all registers, but i was confused how it is if you want to store `edx` into array of `word` because you want to store `32b` into `16b` and `16b`.. i was confused by order of storing but I think I do understand it now. Thank you for you effort :)

Comment: You can't store `32b` in `16b`, [var] points on an address in memory where a byte is placed. When you'll read from this address, size of reading bytes will depend on size of destination register

Comment: Misunderstanding, I meant to store content of register `edx` (which is 32 bits) into array of `word`s (where one element has 16 bits). It is stored as `[var + 0] = dx` and since only half of register was stored, other half is stored into `[var + 2]`. This was what i had not understood, but it makes sense now.

Comment: I'm happy that you understand now